# Call dispatch function with delay laravel

Tags: laravel

```
 dispatch(function () use ($mobile_number,$message) {
             $this->send($mobile_number, $message);
        })->delay(now()->addMinutes(1));
```

this Function return no error but the delay is not working.. How can set that the function is only be executed completely after 1 minlar

Comment: What does $this refer to?

Comment: @MohammadHosseinFereydouni calling send() function.
the Idea is I need to execute the $this->send() only after 1min. without wait in the code

Answer (score 0):

Try putting sleep(60) inside the function before send